# Continuously passing the header in cy.visit

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, http-headers, cypress, e2e-testing

In Cypress, I have an application login scenario. In all scenarios, I have to pass the header parameter. So I have this:

```
cy.visit({
      url: "http://example.com/login",
      headers: { parametr: "value" },
});
```

Unfortunately after login this header is already missing. Is it possible to make this header still present?

I have this:

```
  it("test", () => {
    cy.visit({
      url: "http://example.com/login",
      headers: { parametr: "value" },
    });
    cy.get("#checbox").click();
    cy.get('input[name="username"]').type("test");
    cy.get('input[name="password"]').type("test");
    cy.get("#login").click();
    // no header after logging in - the application does not work.
  });
```